# Bootstrap 3 - Align buttons to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to align two buttons (Apply and Cancel) to a div in order they always be on the bottom of specific div. I tried with position, navbar bottom and a lot of specifications but I can't fixed them. Any help will be preciated.

The main idea is that even when the user expand some collapse element, the buttons don't move to up or down.

Answer here didn't work, maybe for the collapsed control? 
Also I've a bottom footer in the page, I don't know if that is a problem.

JS: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leandro1981/Mk692/2/

Buttons code:

```
 <div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">Cancelar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Continuar</button>
  </div>
```

**Initial State:**

[image: Initial State]

**Wanted State:**

[image]

**Actual State (error):**

[image]

Comment: Please use comment to require more information or links or test, or if you need any help with your help! :D Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do that is to add this CSS:

```
.panel-group {min-height: 258px;}
```

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk692/5/

Comment: uhm, interesting, you are working in the collapsable instead the buttons!! It give me a lot of ideas

Comment: From my experience it's easier than trying to make an element stick to the bottom of something. That's not a pretty solution, but it works.

Comment: The solution is nice, I tried in my app and it works fine :)
The only thing is that now, the subtotal going down with the buttons... but I think is that another question :S